# How to use PHPMyAdmin synchronize?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, synchronization

Who use the feature Synchronize in PHPMyAdmin? Does it work?
I've tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: It is working now. Must have been a server erro. I did the same things and worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Synchronize** option is working fine on PHPMyAdmin 3.3.9.2, it must've been a server problem.
This function is good when developing, but it has its bugs. In one of my Syncs it didn't get some right some words with special characters like 'é','á' etc.
And always make sure of what your doing, a mistake could "erase" data.

Answer (score 0):

**My Experience**:

"PHPMyAdmin Synchronize" did not work out of the box for me. It worked at last though.

**My Home Network Setup**

Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop : 192.168.1.100
Windows VISTA Laptop : 192.168.1.101

Ubuntu has LAMP. VISTA has WAMP.

**When I tried From VISTA Laptop**:

Source : Current Server
Target : 192.168.1.100

I tried to use synchronize from VISTA laptop with above settings.
But it did not work. It gave me an error: (2001  Can't connect to MySQL server)

**When I tried From UBUNTU Desktop**:

Source: 192.168.1.101
Target: Current Server

It just worked!

**Why did this happen?**

From VISTA Laptop:
When I tried to connect from command line using following command:

mysql -h 192.168.1.100 -u  -p

It gave me following error:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.2.100' (10061)

But From UBUNTU Desktop:
When I tried to connect from command line using following command:

mysql -h 192.168.1.101 -u  -p

It got connected.

I am yet to find out, why I could connect from UBUNTU Desktop to VISTA Laptop, but not otherwise.

**In short**
You need to first check the connectivity with the other host using the command mentioned above. If the connectivity & access is there, PHPMyAdmin Synchronize should work, ideally.

Comment: DO you have a snapshot of where this button is exactly? I do not see it on my phpmyadmin

Comment: I am using Version 3.5.1. "Synchronize" appears right at the top. In the same line where you see menus like Databases, Import, Export, etc. Btw, Latest stable version: 4.2.9